# Given a script URL, how do I determine the actual document?

Tags: google-apps-script

I was experimenting with Webextensions earlier this year connecting to scripts in my Google account, but now I cannot determine which script I was connecting to.

So I have the script URL. It looks like a normal script URL, e.g.:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/jG5dForTySatijhf-nmG49F64j62RzkgH6dFgr4SalpUyvF/dev

But I cannot work out which script that URL belongs to! Given a script URL, how do I determine the script in my Google Drive?

---

**UPDATE:**

I think I can phrase my question a little better now, and I cannot imagine I am the first person to have this problem so I imagine there must be some solution.

I have the web app URL (like the one above) for a published script. But I cannot remember which actual script (in my Google Drive) it is associated with.

**Given a web app URL, how do I determine which file in my Google Drive it is associated with?** I know it's one of them but I don't know how to determine which one!

[image]

Comment: TheMaster -- No, that's not true. I think you have misunderstood what I am asking.

Comment: You want to retrieve the project ID from the URL of Web Apps. If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about your question? About the project which are deploying Web Apps, which is the standalone project type or the container-bound script type?

Comment: I don't think that you can get the script file name, or file ID using the "dev" url.  You can get the script ID of the script that the code is in, with `ScriptApp.getScriptId()` Then use DriveApp and get the file and name.  If the script is bound to a document (Sheet, Doc, Form) then the file doesn't show up in your Drive, but you can see a list of bound script in the Apps Script dashboard, which you can get too in various ways.  1) use the link:  https://script.google.com/home 2) Click the Apps Script icon in the upper left when in the code editor

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I can suggest an alternative approach. This would be particularly useful if you have been experimenting with scripts, as you suggest, and have not created a lot of projects.

> All your projects can be found on Google at:
>   https://script.google.com/home

The metadata for each project includes the name of the container, and you open the container from that screen